# fetchedResultsController from 2 entities

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am learning about CoreData and started to use it in one of my project.

I use `fetchedResultsController` to get data out of CoreData to populate a `uitableview` just fine.

The problem I am having is that I need to populate 1 table from 2 Entities. 
This is what I have right now

```
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];

  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

This will only get data from "Contact" Entity but I also need to populate table with data from "Category" Entity as well. And I don't know how to do that.

basically the end result, I would like to have `tableview` show something like 
(assume contact has 3 and category has 2 items)

```
uiTableindex0 :  fetchContact 0

uiTableindex1 :  fetchContact 1

uiTableindex2 :  fetchContact 2

uiTableindex3 :  fetchCategory 1

uiTableindex4 :  fetchCategory 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Suwitcha Sugthana in this condition i would suggest you to populate the data from two different entities into two different arrays suppose they are are (myArray1 and myArray2) by making there `NSFetchRequest` objects differently .And print your two arrays on the cell like this....

```
if(indexPath.row<[myArray1 count])
 {
  cell.text=[myArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
 else 
  cell.text=[myArray2 objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-[myArray1 count])]

//myArray1 has data of contact
//myArray2 has data of catagory
```

And you will get your required format on the table through this..........Hope this may Help u!!!